# error installing ruby gem johnson osx

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to install the gem johnson for a sample application and it's proving to be difficult.  I have ruby version ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0] installed, and trying to install johnson version 2.0.0.pre3 (what the failed bundle install out said).  When trying to install johnson I get a large amount of output, so for now I'll just give the first lines and hope it's enough.

```
sudo gem install johnson -v '2.0.0.pre3'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing johnson:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Comment: I can reproduce this on ruby version 1.9.3-p286 and 1.9.3-p327 (the latest stable version).

Comment: @xxxpigeonxxx I think johnson has a dependency on `spidermonkey` is that installed on your machine

Comment: Yes, I have spidermonkey installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Ruby 1.9 Incompatibility

I can reproduce this problem on my mac with ruby 1.9.3p125.

As far as I can tell Johnson is not compatible with Ruby 1.9.  This issue was raised two years ago https://github.com/jbarnette/johnson/issues/30, however the project has not been updated in the past three years.  On the issue link above, they discuss an experimental 1.9.1 branch that is probably **not** want you want.

Switching to my system ruby (1.8.7) on Mountain Lion allows me to install the gem:

```
$ rvm system
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
$ sudo gem install johnson
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed johnson-1.2.0
1 gem installed
```